# RubyのOcraについて質問です。

Tags: ruby

無限ループの中でタイマーカウント満了の度に処理を行って待ちに入るという動作のプログラムって実はEXE化できないという制約があったりしますでしょうか？

また、その場合の解消方法とかをご存じの方、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　もし何かしらエラーなどが出ているのであれば、そのエラーを質問文に追記してくださるとありがたいです。問題そのものではなく自分で考えた理由について質問してしまう[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/19110)になっていそうです。質問文の下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、どうぞご一考くださいませ。

Comment: 以前tkを使ったRubyのアプリをocraでexeにしていた事があるので、そんな制約はないと思います。